# move any window outside screen under Mac OS

Tags: macos, applescript, accessibility

I am trying to hide (or to move outside teh screen bounds) any window (I mean not belonging to my application).
I tried using Accessibility but unfortunately, there is always a small part of the window which is still on the screen.

Here are my questions:
- Is there a way to completly move a window outside the screen using accessibility?
- Is there an alternative way (Apple Script, ...) to achive that?

Thanks!

---

I am also using Lion and I am quite sure it was working before. 
I am discovering a lot of small things like that in 10.7.
Apple have introduced more changes that it seem.

Thanks for your trial.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code with a TextEdit window. It wouldn't work. I tried to move it off all 4 sides of the screen and none of it worked (as you explained there's always a part of the window showing). I'm using 10.7. I'm pretty sure I could do it in 10.6 and earlier... maybe it's a 10.7 thing???

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "TextEdit"
        set theWindows to windows
        repeat with aWindow in theWindows
            tell aWindow
                set currentPosition to position
                set position to {-1000, item 2 of currentPosition}
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```